# replacing text that has url with an anchor with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 var a = document.querySelectorAll('.post .content div');
 var b = a[7].childNodes;
 for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  if(b[i].nodeType === 3){
     var ahref = document.createElement('a');
     ahref.className="easyBBurlFetch";
     ahref.href=b[i].nodeValue.replace(exp,'$1');
     ahref.innerText=b[i].nodeValue.replace(exp,'$1');
    b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(ahref,b[i]);
    b[i].parentNode.removeChild(b[i].nextSibling);
   }
  }
```

Someone gave me the answer as I had this code though it wasn't working correct. Though I have the issue now if my text is like so:

```
This is just a test so click here www.youtube.com which then becomes

 <a href="www.youtube.com%20which%20then%20becomes">www.youtube.com%20which%20then%20becomes</a>
```

It doesn't event keep the first line of text, I just need to parse the url while keeping the surrounding text.

In need the output to save the actual surrounding text but parse the urls that are inside the text to html anchor tags `<a>` so that they can then be clickable and actually follow through to a real website and not have unnessarcy text inside it from what my user was writing about. Thank you

**UPDATE**
I've got closer to making this work-- But I'm having a problem with the first text in the string is saying `Undefined` I've been debugging this and can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Here is code

```
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('.post');
  var b = a[0].childNodes;
  var textArray;
  var ahref;
  for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
if (b[i].nodeType === 3) {
    var newHTML;
    textArray = b[i].textContent.split(" ");
    for (var j = 0; j < textArray.length; j++) {
        if (textArray[j] !== "" && validURL(textArray[j])) {
            ahref = document.createElement('a');
            ahref.href = (/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/).test(textArray[j]) ? textArray[j] : "http://" + textArray[j];
            ahref.innerText = textArray[j];
            ahref.className = "easyURLparse";
            textArray[j] = ahref;
        }
        newHTML+= textArray[j].outerHTML ? textArray[j].outerHTML + " " : textArray[j] + " ";

    }
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = newHTML;
    newHTML = "";
    b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div, b[i]);
    b[i].parentNode.removeChild(b[i].nextSibling);
}
  }

  function validURL(str) {
var pattern = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?");
if (!pattern.test(str)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
   }
```

**[Testing Code](http://jsfiddle.net/fRFv8/3/)**

Just need to figure out the undefined and why it's adding it

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. Could you add some html that shows what you have for example `<a href="http://hasURL">my URL-Text<a>` and then what you would like it to be after replacing the text `<a href=#anchorToURL>replacedText<a/>` I also do not understand which text should be replaced by which other text.

Comment: Yes sure, here is a bin with what's happening http://jsbin.com/eriJASi/2/edit  almost, it's changing the whole line.

Comment: Your pattern matches stuff, that starts with a [word-boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), followed by `http`, `https`, `ftp` or `file`. An anchor starts with `#` your sample html starts with `www`.

Comment: How does an anchor start with `#` any anchor tag could be `<a href="youtube.com></a> or <a href="#">tag</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com>google</a>` it doesn't matter whats in the anchor. I'm searching text nodes and converting the urls to actual anchors... the `a` is called `anchor`

Comment: Assuming we're talking about the [href Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp).

Comment: I took the regex from user jingyinggong and [forked your jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oTupiPU/1/edit) but i am still not sure if it does what you want.

Comment: Assuming either way, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html  it is considered to be basically the same terminology, almost every html element initial corresponds to a name. IE `b = bold, i=italic, a=anchor/link, div=division,td=table data,tr=table row, etc` anyways @threeFourOneSixOneThree I'll check it out

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree no that is not it, It needs to convert to a url specifically. Like so: http://jsbin.com/eriJASi/2/edit

Comment: So i understood the following: i have a huge string that contains normal text, text that matches an URL and random html-tags. I would like to parse the string and create links for any valid URL inside the huge string. So this `some text followed by a valid url http://google.com followed by some tags <br /> by another ULR to somewhere ftp://foo.org/cats.jpg` will become this `some text followed by a valid url <a href=http://google.com>google.com</a> followed by some tags <br /> by another ULR to somewhere <a href=ftp://foo.org/cats.jpg>foo.org/cats.jpg</a>` Is this it?

Comment: Yes that is it . Tags don't matter really in the sense as it'll break them into different parts if the returned array. `br` is mode Type 1 and text is nodetype 3 ;) anyways you have the right idea

Comment: Now who done down voted the question. Give me a reason and Ill fix it darn it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var a = document.querySelectorAll('.post');
 var b = a[0].childNodes;
 var textArray;
 var ahref;
   for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
       var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
     if (b[i].nodeType === 3) {
       var newHTML;
       if (validURL(b[i].textContent)) {
        textArray = b[i].textContent.split(" ");
        for (var j = 0; j < textArray.length; j++) {
            if (textArray[j] !== undefined && textArray[j] !== "" && validURL(textArray[j]) && textArray[j] !== null) {
                ahref = document.createElement('a');
                ahref.href = (/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/).test(textArray[j]) ? textArray[j] : "http://" + textArray[j];
                ahref.innerText = textArray[j];
                ahref.className = "easyURLparse";
                textArray[j] = ahref;
            }
            newHTML += textArray[j].outerHTML ? textArray[j].outerHTML + " " : textArray[j] + " ";
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = newHTML;
        div.className = "easyDiv";
        b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div, b[i]);
        b[i].parentNode.removeChild(b[i].nextSibling);
    }
    newHTML = "";
}
 }

function validURL(str) {
var pattern = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?");
if (!pattern.test(str)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
 }
```

By taking the textNodes and splitting them into an array I can then change the url into an html element. Then taking the array elements seeing if there is outerHTML or not then placing it in a new string and replacing that textNode now with a workable link.

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fRFv8/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

this regexp will do the job

```
exp = /href="(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])"/ig;
```